# ViewBag vs Session variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, viewbag

I am being asked to switch out my use of a Session variable for `ViewBag.Property`.

> In BaseAdminInterfaceController.cs - please do not use `Session[<string>]` and instead use `ViewBag.Property`. The reasoning for this is that the OnActionExecuting method is executed multiple times per request and therefore storing to Session (which saves beyond the request lifecycle) is unnecessary, ViewBag is simple, new, and works well in this case.

Here is the code in a BaseController:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    if (Session["House"] == null) Session["House"] = Enums.Houses.Black;
}
```

My issue here is that the life of `ViewBag.Property` only exists during the current request.  It cannot be used to pass a variable from action to action, or view back to the controller. Is ViewBag better?

Comment: I've managed to make ASP.Net sites for several years now without having to touch the session object. It's not so common to use these days as it's not scalable (i.e. uses server memory) and just doesn't work without considerable effort in a web farm. Are you really sure you need to pass the value between action methods? That seems odd.

Comment: if data should persist between requests and short using cookie may be better. if you need to pass data between particular actions, using querystring or form data may be better.

Comment: Who is asking you to do that change? Why don't you ask them why they feel the change is required?

Comment: It is necessary to save a particular variable for a users' session.  You think that Cookies are better than the Session variable?

Comment: Session has also been frowned upon since the classic ASP days. Maintaining it per page adds overhead for each request, it's brittle, it eats memory and can de-stabilize an app if it isn't managed well, you have to constantly be sure it didn't go away and need to rehydrate it, etc.. Basically, ViewBag is useful since it flows through all the views that will be rendered for the action, then politely goes away and doesn't persist unnecessarily.

Comment: Ask yourself whether you really need to persist this variable between requests or not. Can't it simply be a default value in a viewmodel? It's not clear simply from the code you've written...some more context would help. Perhaps the person reviewing it has that context and think it's unnecessary. If you're unsure, you could always ask them.